# How to get selecteditems in CheckedComboBoxEdit?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I am using the MVVM pattern in my project;
 In my project I have a `CheckedComboBoxEdit` then bind to a `Person` List;

```cs
Public Class Person
{
  Public Int Id { get; set; }
  Public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When User select some Items in `CheckedComboBoxEdit`, how can I get `CheckedComboBoxEdit` `SelectedItems` in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You need a property on your ViewModel that binds to the [`CheckedComboBoxEdit`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic) `SelectedItems` property. You should probably look at [related DevExpress posts](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q321049.aspx).

```xml
<CheckedComboBoxEdit x:Name="cbPeople" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPeople}" ... />
```